# Youtube not playing in android's react-native WebView

Tags: android, webview, react-native

I've got a problem playing Youtube(or any) video in react-native's webview on android device. iOS works just fine.

I've already looked at several SO related questions, but everyone seem to suggest two things:

1. `webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());` which is as far as I am concerned default in react-native's webview since few versions later
2. enable hardware acceleration `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` in `AndroidManifest.xml` (which I have done)

All I got is a rendered player with controls and everything, but black screen.

Comment: Is it a device or simulator? If it's the latter then it may miss YouTube app which must be installed separately. I see YouTube playing in WebView with react-native just fine.

Comment: It might not be able to fetch the video file. Make sure it can connect to the outside network (sometimes finicky with simulators)

Comment: I'm having the same issue.

Comment: I have the same issue.